# Flutter or Dart, how to change ui.Image (content) color, not background?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ui.Image` which has already been decoded. It contains only white background and black content, let's a "question" mark there.

I will use `Canvas` and `drawImage` to paint the `ui.Image` after I change color from black to red or another single color.

Comment: How about using Imagefilter

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it should have worked, however as I mentioned, I wont change the whole image, the background will keep white or transparent. 
This means, I want to selected some pixels on the image and change them. WDYT?

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/image

```
        Image image;//decode image from your image
        
        //get Pixel at x,y and check if Color is Black
        image.getPixel(x, y); 
        //setPixelSafe set pixel at x,y to new color
        image.setPixelSafe(x, y, newColor);
        
        //convert Image to ui.Image and Draw it in Canvas
```